# how to trigger a zone file save from dnspython after an update

Tags: python, python-2.7, dnspython

I am using dnspython to perform dynamic DNS updates using a syntax similar to:

```
import dns.update, dns.query
update = dns.update.Update('zone', keyring=keyring)
update.add('source', 60, 'CNAME', 'destination')
response = dns.query.tcp(update, 'localhost')
```

This works well, except that I want the changes to the zone file to be written to disk. Does anyone know how to trigger such an update?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's an example on [this page](http://agiletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2005/08/managing-dns-zone-files-with-dnspython.html) under the heading "Modifying a DNS zone file".

Comment: Yeah, that's the same page I had found. Unfortunately it talks about doing that when using dns.zone. I thought for dynamic DNS updates, you're supposed to use dns.update, but perhaps I will have to settle for using dns.zone and incrementing the serial myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use RNDC, using a crontab - but since you are in Python... this does it for me:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import syslog, isc

dom = 'domain.example'

r = isc.rndc(('127.0.0.1', 953), 'hmac-sha256', 'MjB5u4QLSlL5EGFtD/etc=')
ret = r.call('sync %s' % dom)
if ret['result'] != '0':
  syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, "Error writing zone: %s %s" % (dom, ret['err']))
else:  
  syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_NOTICE, "Zone written to disk: %s" % dom)
```

Comment: For anyone wondering about compatibility: The `isc.rndc` Python module was added in BIND 9.11.0, which was released on 2016-10-04: ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.11.0/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out bind just spits out the zone file every 15 minutes. For my purposes, I can take a backup of the journal file as the reason why I wanted the changes reflected was to be able to fire up named (after a failure) and have up-to-date records in place.